# Insert into multiple tables based on group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql

My question relates to MySQL.
Assuming I have table named "shapes" that contains all kind of shapes.

I can get the count per shape type as follows:

```
select day, shape_type, count(*) from shapes group by day, shape_type
```

In my particular setup the database exists already and on the other end of the pipeline i have a set of tables as follows:

```
sum_square_day
sum_rectangle_day
sum_circle_day
```

Is it possible to have an SQL that query only once from shapes and insert into the other tables?

In other terms I know I could do 3 statements:

```
    INSERT INTO sum_square_day (day,count)
    SELECT day,count FROM (
      SELECT day, count(*) from shapes where shape_type = "square") AS tmp_shapes
```

And then for circle and rectangle but that would require going 3 times to shapes.

Could i do one statements to shapes that group by shape_type and then utilize the result to put it in each respective table?

Thx

Comment: Why would you have three separate tables for the daily counts?

Comment: And why store those values? Create a view instead!

Comment: I don't have control on why the data model is like that, it's just like that for historical reasons. Also the way i told the problem is simplified, the data model itself is much more complex and with many more fields. One of the reason there are multiple tables is because each table has a completely different set of columns.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to solve it by just one statement, but for having a better performance I would recommend the following:

Create a temp table with the result of the original select. This way the COUNT and GROUP BY commands (which take more time) will be executed only once.

```
select day, shape_type, count(*) 
into temp_table 
from shapes 
group by day, shape_type
```

Then execute the 3 INSERT commands:

```
INSERT INTO sum_square_day (day,count)
SELECT day,count 
FROM temp_table 
WHERE shape_type = "square"
```

At the end drop the temp table.